# How to create comparison tables in Python

Tags: python

I want to generate comparison tables [like this](http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/5677/22862352.png) by using Python.

[alt text http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/5677/22862352.png](http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/5677/22862352.png)

Can you suggest any library to do this?

Comment: [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's surely the output of TeX. It would take all of 60 minutes to learn enough TeX ([or, better yet, LaTeX](http://andy-roberts.net/misc/latex/latextutorial4.html)) to spit out tables like that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - but  I want to create PNG files (or any kind of image format) that looks like this table. I'm coding a project in Python and I want to create comparison tables of different results by using Python. I don't know how to draw something like a table.

Comment: One approach is to output the LaTeX commands you'd use to generate that table, then call LaTeX on your output to generate the table.  This is probably overkill, though.

Comment: Yes. If you use LaTeX, following the instructions on the page I link to, you'll get identical results to the image you show. LaTeX is a typesetting system with a textual input. Your program would spit out LaTeX source, and run LaTeX on that source, generating the table as seen in the image above.

Answer (score 0):

Reportlab has some great tools for creating and formatting tables. The only drawback from your perspective is that it outputs to PDF, so you would need an intermediate step to convert the output to PNG. Take a look at the [Reportlab User Guide](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) for more information on Reportlab tables.

Here is some code I whipped up which would create something very similar to your example image:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from reportlab.platypus import Frame, Table
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.lib.colors import black

canvas = Canvas("table_test.pdf")
frame = Frame(10*mm, 10*mm, 190*mm, 280*mm) 

# Some mock data for the table. The data must be supplied as a list of lists:
table_data = [['Datasets', 'COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3', 'COL4', 'COL5'],
             ['ROW0',
              u'6.43 \xb1 4.72',
              u'6.16 \xb1 3.83',
              u'2.79 \xb1 5.43',
              u'19.08 \xb1 1.12',
              u'1.76 \xb1 4.88'],
             ['ROW1',
              u'1.09 \xb1 2.42',
              u'11.51 \xb1 1.29',
              u'10.14 \xb1 0.76',
              u'10.09 \xb1 0.63',
              u'27.16 \xb1 3.88'],
             ['ROW2',
              u'0.88 \xb1 5.83',
              u'23.13 \xb1 4.54',
              u'8.96 \xb1 4.94',
              u'4.30 \xb1 0.30',
              u'13.20 \xb1 1.31'],
             ['ROW3',
              u'22.87 \xb1 2.22',
              u'8.56 \xb1 0.91',
              u'6.36 \xb1 1.69',
              u'4.30 \xb1 4.74',
              u'12.39 \xb1 3.49'],
             ['ROW4',
              u'14.35 \xb1 5.04',
              u'15.29 \xb1 2.17',
              u'8.39 \xb1 3.05',
              u'11.38 \xb1 3.02',
              u'10.21 \xb1 4.23']]

table_style = [("BOX", (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.5, black), # box around table
               ("LINEBELOW", (0, 0), (-1, 0), 0.5, black), # line under header
               ("LINEAFTER", (0, 0), (0, -1), 0.5, black), # vertical line
               ("LINEAFTER", (1, 0), (1, -1), 0.5, black), # vertical line
               ("LINEAFTER", (2, 0), (2, -1), 0.5, black), # vertical line
               ("LINEAFTER", (3, 0), (3, -1), 0.5, black), # vertical line
               ("LINEAFTER", (4, 0), (4, -1), 0.5, black), # vertical line
               ]

table = Table(table_data, style=table_style)
frame.add(table, canvas)
canvas.save()
```